# Firebase console shows empty identifier for custom authentication

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

I use a custom auth scheme for Firebase. Tokens are generated by my `nodejs` backend:

```
mFirebase
        .getAuth(token)
        .createCustomToken(uid, claims)
        .then(sendToken)
        .
        .
```

When I check out the "Users" section of Firebase console, the "Identifier" field is always empty.

I wonder if this is the expected behavior or I can provide additional things from my backend such as the username or email, to be displayed there.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected. You need to set the email on the user if you want it to show.
You have 2 options.

set before you mint custom token:

```
return admin.auth().createUser({
  uid: 'customUserUid',
  email: 'user@example.com'
}).then((userRecord) => {
  return admin.auth().createCustomToken(userRecord.uid);
}).catch((error) => {
  // Error.
});
```

Update user email client side after sign in:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(customToken).then((result) => {
  return result.user.updateEmail(userEmail);
}).catch((error) => {
  // Error.
});
```